# S2S, same app registration for client and server Azure AD (self authentication)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, active-directory, authorization

The subject says it all.

I cannot find anything related in the documentation.

So I have the API with authentication. It triggers background service which needs to access authenticated API. I need service to service authentication, client_credentials flow

I created tenant and single app registration.
Can I use credentials form this App Registration to acquire the token and to authenticate calls?

It does not seem to work for me. So I am curious if there is anything I could miss in configs or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and exposed an Api in the Azure Ad Application and added the scope like below:

[image]

And granted the **Admin consent** for the scope:

[image]

I used **client-credential flow** to acquire the token by using below paramters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:******
scope:api://ClientID/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

> **Note** that: The scenario you are trying to achieve is not feasible, and for more security and scalability it is recommended to register both client and server Azure AD applications for self-authentication.

**Reference:**

[Set up Azure Active Directory for client authentication in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-setup-azure-ad-via-portal)